# pandas conditional statements and adding columns

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I am using Pandas to sort through an excel spreadsheet. I would like to execute an if/elif function to return a string in a new column within my dataframe. I am trying to return a new column named "action" that returns a string based off time values.

```
state     time      
 ca         1
 ca         5
 ca         7
 ca         10

for rows in df:

 if df[time]>=1:
    return "do nothing"

 elif df[time]<=5:
     return "add more"

 elif df[time]<=10:
      return "add less"

  else:
      return "error"
```

Comment: do you have a more specific question or error?

Comment: please accept answers that solved your questions

Answer (score 4):

IIUC we can use [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [167]: df['new'] = pd.cut(df.time, 
                             bins=[-np.inf, 1, 5, 10, np.inf], 
                             labels=['do nothing','add more','add less','error'])

In [168]: df
Out[168]:
  state  time         new
0    ca     1  do nothing
1    ca     5    add more
2    ca     7    add less
3    ca    10    add less
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.searchsorted`

```
labels = np.array(['do nothing', 'add more', 'add less', 'error'])
df.assign(new=labels[np.searchsorted([1, 5, 10], df.time.values)])

  state  time         new
0    ca     1  do nothing
1    ca     5    add more
2    ca     7    add less
3    ca    10    add less
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a simple way to add a column for each condition in pandas.

```python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO("""state,time
ca,1
ca,5
ca,7
ca,10""")
df = pd.read_csv(csv)
# Out[1]:
#   state  time
# 0    ca           1
# 1    ca           5
# 2    ca           7
# 3    ca          10

def add_action(row):
    if row["time"] <= 1:
        return "do nothing"
    elif row["time"] <= 5:
        return "add more"
    elif row["time"] <= 10:
        return "add less"
    else:
        return "error"

df = df.assign(action=df.apply(add_action, axis=1))
# Out[2]: 
#   state  time      action
# 0    ca     1  do nothing
# 1    ca     5    add more
# 2    ca     7    add less
# 3    ca    10    add less
```